# Satisfy two conditions in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

I execute a process with Java. The process never terminate and scan the machine looking for some file, when it found one of them it prints the path of the file. I want to execute the process for a certain time and get the output. This is a piece of my code

```
  BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
Process p = pb.start();
    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime )){ //loop 1
     while((line=stdInput.readLine()) != null){ loop 2
        System.out.println(line);
       }
    }
p.destroy();
```

the problem is that if the script doesn't find a result for a short time loop 2 will exit and never run again during the period.

I also tried

```
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime ) || (line=stdInput.readLine()) != null))
```

But in this case if `stdInput.readLine()` still returning results the loop will not end even if the time is ended.

```
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime ) && (line=stdInput.readLine()) != null))
```

In this case the loop will exit if `line=stdInput.readLine()` doesn't return a result even if the time is not ended

**Edit:**
I tried this code

```
System.out.println("Before while");
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime ){
        System.out.println("while");    
         if(line=stdInput.readLine())!= null){
          System.out.println("One line");
        }
    }
        p.destroy();
```

If the process is not detecting anything the loop never end, this is the output

ok
before while
while

System.out.println("while"); was called just one time when it was supposed to be called for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean :

```
while ((System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime ){
    if(line=stdInput.readLine())!= null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks it looks fine but it's not working, I updated the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the short-circut &&.

Use &, this will make sure it both conditions are checked. With && if the first one was false the whole thing is short circutted.

You want the readLine() to execute even regardless right? with && the second condition will never even be looked at if the first condition is false.

& will check both then make a decision.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how this will help me in my case

Answer (score 0):

If stdInput comes from a scanner, it probably will never be null. Show a bit more of your code.

And as for what madmax said, yes, do short-circut. For 0 AND 1 = 0, which means 0 AND something = 0. It's math.

Comment: Yes it's a scanner

Comment: Then it's like I said. By stating `while((line=stdInput.readLine()) != null){}` you are basicaly saying "While the input that I receive from the scanner is not null, I continue the loop.". I don't see a way for it to end like that. 
<br>
What You can do is `while( !(line=stdInput.readLine()).isEmpty() && (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime ) ){}`. Like this you are verifying if the input is an empty String AND if the current time is less than the endTime.

Comment: Taking what I said above, instead of `!(line=stdInput.readLine()).isEmpty()`, you could use a flag, so it would be something like: `!(line=stdInput.readLine().equals( flag ))`.